# Where can I find a website that provides free textures

Tags: texturing

I am looking for a website that provides texture 'images' bump and specular maps included. High resolution would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.textures.com/
You just need to create an acount, and you will be able to download 15 free textures per day